# SQLite update column if another column exists

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, sqlite

Okay, so I'm not sure exactly how to name this question but I can explain what my issue is. I'm creating a webbrowser, and using an sqlite database to store the history. When the page finished loading my method:

```
-(void)addHistory:(NSString*)title address:(NSString*)url{
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

     if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_historyDB) == SQLITE_OK)
     {
         NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                @"UPDATE HISTORY SET title='%@' WHERE url='%@'", title, url];

         const char *update_stmt = [updateSQL UTF8String];

         sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
         if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_historyDB, update_stmt, -1, &stmt, NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {
             NSLog(@"Updated");
         }else{
             NSString *insertSQL =
             [NSString stringWithFormat:
              @"INSERT INTO HISTORY (title, url, visits, date, search) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",
              title, url, @"todo", @"todo", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", title, url]];

             const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
             sqlite3_prepare_v2(_historyDB, insert_stmt,
                                -1, &statement, NULL);
             if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
             {
                 NSLog(@"Added Entry");
             } else {
                 NSLog(@"Coundn't Add Entry");
             }
             sqlite3_finalize(statement);
         }
         sqlite3_close(_historyDB);
    }
}
```

I assumed that if the update failed (because the url is not present in the table) it would move to the else statement and add the key. The main idea behind this is to update the title of the webpage, and once that is working, update other fields such as last visited, amount of times viewed and so on..

I've experimented with a variety of different methods but I just can't seem to achieve the desired results.

Comment: I think you have to check the record is present or not to decide update or insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making the switch to [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), a brilliant Objective-C wrapper for SQLite. I then performed a `SELECT`statement where the url matched the current one, if it returned a value I updated the database, if not, I simply added to it.

Answer (score 0):

To execute the update statement, you must call `sqlite3_step` for that statement.
To find out how many records were updated, call [`sqlite3_changes`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/changes.html).

And you must handle any errors returned by the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` calls.

And you must call `sqlite3_finalize` for `stmt`.

And any website with `'` in its URL or title will corrupt your SQL statements; to avoid [SQL injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/), use [parameters](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html).